# Parse csv and append if no match found

Tags: python, csv

please help
I want to check csv first on "final link" below in code and append csv only if there is no match found:

Thanks in advance

```
for i in range(0,1):
    with open('plaid.csv', 'a') as f_object:
        writer_object = csv.writer(f_object)
        url = f'https://plaidonline.com/products?closeout=True&page={i}'
        r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
        product_block = soup.select('div', class_='col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-lg-9 ')
        for i in product_block:
            href = i.find_all(class_='tile-link', href=True)
            for link in href:
                link = link.get('href')
                final_link = 'https://plaidonline.com/'+link
                if final_link not in product_urls:
                    product_urls.append(final_link)
                    # print(final_link)
                    writer_object.writerow(final_link)
                    f_object.close()
```

Comment: Where and how is `product_urls` declared/initialized? What does your code do and how does it differ from what you want?

Comment: Also, it is very bad practice to use the same variable name in two nested loops. It is non-descriptive, error-prone and makes your code difficult to read